# NuGet Install Matching Pattern Version

Tags: nuget, semantic-versioning, nuget-cli

How do you install a nuget package with a matching pattern:
For example, I want nuget to get any version matching the pattern `1.0.0*` (`1.1.0-rc`, `1.1.0.1`, etc...).

But nuget doesn't support the wildcard character, I get an error `'1.1.0*' is not a valid version string`

And running:
`nuget install <mypackage> -Version 1.0.0 -Source <myserver>`
Will only resolve `1.0.0` version and nothing else.

I actually wrote a script that queries the server for version, and picks whatever I want, but I wonder if there's a native way of doing that using just the nuget CLI.

Comment: I might be mistaken but couldn't you just use wildcard versions in your `packages.config` or `.csproj`? I'm assuming you know the id of the package you want to install.

Comment: @JoakimSkoog haven't tried that yet, maybe it's a good idea actually if it works, for my specific solution though I was using plain nuget CLI, since I use nuget packages for storing versioned build artifacts rather than actual packages/references for .NET projects.

Comment: @JoakimSkoog can't use * in packages.config as well

Comment: You're right, you can't use the star wildcard but you can use something similar. Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards

Comment: @JoakimSkoog note that the `packages.config` part doesn't provide anything usefull, you can use the wildcard * in a csproj, but that doesn't really provide a solution.
So far, I'm just using a script, with: `nuget list <package> -AllVersion -Source <server> | findstr <version>`